# Android - Remove an item from arraylist by its ID

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an arraylist in my adapter ( RecyclerView ) .

I have to delete an item from array list by its ID :

```
public static ArrayList<News> newsList = new ArrayList<News>();
```

I filled array list like below :

```
News n = new News();
n.id = data.getString("from_user_id");
n.comments = data.getString("message");
n.title = data.getString("name");
n.time = time;
newsList.add(n);
```

I want to remove an item from this list by its id ( **n.id** ) value .

How can i do this ?

Comment: loop through list and check if id matches and remove

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' Im new . please let me know how can i do ?

Comment: Do this 
if(removeId.equals(n.id))
     newsList.remove(n.id);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < newsList.size() ; i++){
        if("yourId".equalsIgnoreCase(newsList.get(i).id)){
            newsList.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "yourID" is not fixed

Answer (score 3):

Loop through list and check if id matches and remove. Like :

```
public static ArrayList<News> newsList = new ArrayList<News>();
News newsToRemove;
for(News news : newsList) {
    if(news.getId() == yourId) {
        newsToRemove = news;
        break;
    }
}
if(newsToRemove != null) {
    newsList.remove(newsToRemove);
}
```

Comment: "yourid" is not fixed ..i want to remove duplicate from arraylist

Comment: @AjayMistry This answer is optimised keeping in mind that there are no duplicates in the Arraylist. If there are duplicates then try the code which is marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
public deleteItemById(int Id){
      for(int i=0;i<newsList.size();i++){
         if(newsList.getItem(i).getid()==Id){
            newsList.remove(i);
          }
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, surly this will help you

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < "YOURLIST.size();" ; i++){
    if("IDTOREMOVE".equalsIgnoreCase(REALID){
        YOURLIST.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple guys no need to check index etc suppose **ItemList** is list of **n element** and you want to remove **itme** base on **id** so u can use these code; Replace your condition id insted of your id;

```
for(Object item : ItemList)
  if(item.id == your id)
     ItemList.remove(item);
```